# Place second part of a string at the first place

Tags: powershell, scripting

I have a string "givenname surname". What I want is to turn this "surname, givenname". First I thought I would need to somehow place the surname at the first place, then replace the empty space with a comma and space.

I do not have any code yet :C sry.

Comment: `'firstname lastname' -replace '(\w+)\s+(\w+)', '$2, $1'`

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers yep that worked, now explain why ^^

Comment: SO is not a place where other people read the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_regular_expressions) to you. Consider that your homework.

Comment: $x = @("givenname surname" -split ' '); [array]::Reverse($x); $x = $x -join ', '

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agreed on @ansgar wiechers's comment.

```
$str = "Firstname Lastname"
$str -replace '(\w+)\s+(\w+)','$2, $1'
```

**Output :**

```
Lastname, Firstname
```